# Обновлять скрипты по ID самого обьекта

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Вот проект простой ,запись идет в "инпут" которое находится вправом меню снизу и только при нажатии "ЗАПОЛНИТЬ" начинает заполняться контейнер с водой.
[image]
Есть скрипт, пока что один, есть ли какой-то скрипт который будет обновлять другие скрипты, а не просто перезагружать страницу полностью?

```
$(function () {
atualizaProgresso = function () {
    var percent = $('input[type=number]').val();
    var atual = $('.barra-progresso .concluido').data('p');
    percent = percent > 100 ? 100 : percent;
    mudaNumero(atual, percent);
    $('.barra-progresso .concluido').animate({
        height: percent + '%'
    }, {
        duration: 300,
        easing: "swing"
    });
    $('.barra-progresso .concluido').data('p', percent);
};
$('button').click(atualizaProgresso);
$('.barra-progresso .concluido').data('p', 0);
atualizaProgresso();
});

function mudaNumero(de, para) {
if (typeof timer1 == "number") {
    clearInterval(timer1);
}

decimo = (para - de) / 10;
para = parseInt(para, 10);
de = parseInt(de, 10);

vezes = 1;
timer1 = window.setInterval(function () {
    if (vezes == 10) {
        clearInterval(timer1);
    }
    de = de + parseFloat(decimo, 10);
    $('.barra-progresso .percentual .numero').html(Math.round(de));
    vezes++;
     }, 30);
  }
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
     var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
     $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
     });
```

Comment: Что значит *обновлять другие скрипты*?

Comment: Имеется скрипт для progress bar  ,туда записываются числовые данные но они обновляются только когда я нажму подтверждение  записи или просто обновлю страницу полностью например . А нужно чтоб при записи числа отображался уровень этого progress bar просто с каким-то интервалом не зависимо от того записал я данные или не записал .

Comment: Если честно, понятнее не стало. При записи числа куда? Какого числа? Пожалуйста, отредактируйте ваш вопрос, постарайтесь более полно описать проблему.

Comment: Весь код не могу скнинуть , много места займет . Сбросил скрин ,описание как оно работает ну и сам скрипт progress box

Comment: Давайте так. Вы опишите, что должно происходить. Желательно по шагам. Например:1) Нажимаем кнопку "Заполнить". 2) Должно произойти что-то. 3) Еще что-то. И так далее.

Comment: Обновлять скрипты? Может вызывать функции повторно с другими параметрами. 
Вы можете объявить функцию и вызывать её без перезагрузки страницы просто меняя в ней параметры. Или написать какую нибудь функцию конструктор.

Comment: Без нажатия на "Заполнить" .  Я записываю данные в поле и БЕЗ ПЕРЕЗАГРУЗКИ страницы должно сразу заполняться уровень воды .(синего цвета прямоугольник)

Comment: То есть у меня сейчас данные обновляются и меняется уровень воды по нажатию (подтверждению) на "ЗАПОЛНИТЬ" а нужно чтоб только в поле записал и оно сразу показывает уровень воды . Записал 5 - отобразился уровень воды на 5 , записал на 30 - отобразилось на 30 .

Comment: Есть какие-то варианты ?

Comment: Отпишите пожалуйста .